# Retrieve the MAC address of a device through a Python program while connecting two computers via cable?

Tags: python, configuration, wifi

How can we use python code to connect two computers via cable and get mac address of one device in a small window?

Have to configure multiple devices for wifi connectivity in my domain. finding it difficult to type mac address of each device coming for configuration.

Comment: Immediate issue is that MAC is bound to network adapter, not device. Cable connection will use different MAC than wireless.

Comment: How are you connecting them? If it's an Ethernet cable, you can't communicate with the device unless you know its Ethernet MAC address.

Comment: Is the computer from which you're trying to get the mac somehow special? Otherwise wouldn't it be a lot simpler just write a script to get the mac and send it somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Your wifi access point is probably a router with DHCP server. And your device is probably DHCP enabled. Your device is asking for an IP address from your router at power-up.
Look at your router report too get the IP and MAC.